# Combining csv files in R with different variable types

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine multiple csv files with the same variables but some csv files have 'ZIP' as characters and others have 'ZIP' as numbers, so it won't allow me to use bind_rows().

Is there any way I can add to this to convert each 'ZIP' variable in the csv files to characters so I can apply bind_rows()?

Thanks,

```
df <- list.files(path = "/Users/XXXX", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `col_types` when you read the files. Perhaps

```r
df <- list.files(path = "/Users/XXXX", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  lapply(read_csv, col_types = c(Zip = "character")) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Comment: That did the job, thank you!